# SQLAlchemy - "must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Just migrated my code to work with Postgres instead of SQLite where everything was working fine. I am using SQLAlchemy to generate all of my SQL, and I am now getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1248, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 580, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.GroupingError: column "movie_category_scores.votes" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT movie_category_scores.votes >= 10 AS anon_1, movie_ca...
               ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/movieelo/cinelow/my_server/database/pers_movie_dbf.py", line 187, in get_common_categories
    cats = MovieCategoryScores.query.filter(MovieCategoryScores.movie_id.in_([movie1, movie2])).group_by(MovieCategoryScores.category_id).having(func.count(MovieCategoryScores.category_id) > 1).all()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3186, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3342, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3367, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 988, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1101, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1252, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1473, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 152, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1248, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 580, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.GroupingError) column "movie_category_scores.votes" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT movie_category_scores.votes >= 10 AS anon_1, movie_ca...
               ^

[SQL: SELECT movie_category_scores.votes >= %(param_1)s AS anon_1, movie_category_scores.movie_id AS movie_category_scores_movie_id, movie_category_scores.category_id AS movie_category_scores_category_id, movie_category_scores.score AS movie_category_scores_score, movie_category_scores.votes AS movie_category_scores_votes 
FROM movie_category_scores 
WHERE movie_category_scores.movie_id IN (%(movie_id_1)s, %(movie_id_2)s) GROUP BY movie_category_scores.category_id 
HAVING count(movie_category_scores.category_id) > %(count_1)s]
[parameters: {'param_1': 10, 'movie_id_1': 550, 'movie_id_2': 11, 'count_1': 1}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

The error is triggered when I run this function:

```py
def get_common_categories(movie1, movie2):
    cats = MovieCategoryScores.query.filter(MovieCategoryScores.movie_id.in_([movie1, movie2])).group_by(MovieCategoryScores.category_id).having(func.count(MovieCategoryScores.category_id) > 1).all()
    categories = []
    for cat in cats:
        categories.append(cat.category.serialize)
    return categories
```

But the top of the error is actually referencing another function that doesn't have anything to do with the one I'm triggering, namely this one:

```py
def get_category_score(movie_id, category_id):
    query = db.session.query(
    MovieCategoryScores,
    func.rank()\
        .over(
            order_by=MovieCategoryScores.score.desc(),
            partition_by=MovieCategoryScores.category_id,
        )\
        .label('rank')
    ).filter(or_(MovieCategoryScores.votes >= 10, MovieCategoryScores.movie_id == movie_id))
    # now filter
    query = query.filter(MovieCategoryScores.category_id == category_id)
    query = query.order_by(MovieCategoryScores.category_id, 'rank')
    all_movies = query.subquery()
    new_query = db.session.query(all_movies).filter(all_movies.c.movie_id == movie_id)
    my_movie = new_query.first()
    return my_movie
```

They interact with association tables and a movie table that look like this:

```py
class MovieCategoryScores(db.Model):
    movie_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('movie.id'), primary_key=True)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'), primary_key=True)
    score = db.Column(db.Integer)
    votes = db.Column(db.Integer)
    category = relationship("Category", back_populates="movies")
    movie = relationship("Movie", back_populates="categories")

class MoviePersonScores(db.Model):
    movie_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('movie.id'), primary_key=True)
    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'), primary_key=True)
    job = db.Column(db.String(30), primary_key=True) #0 = actor, 1 = director, 2 = writer
    score = db.Column(db.Integer)
    votes = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    person = relationship("Person", back_populates="movies")
    movie = relationship("Movie", back_populates="people")

class Movie(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable = False)
    poster_path = db.Column(db.String(30))
    categories = relationship("MovieCategoryScores", back_populates="movie")
    people = relationship("MoviePersonScores", back_populates="movie")

    @property
    def serialize(self):
        return {
            'id'    : self.id,
            'name'  : self.name,
            'poster_path' : self.poster_path
        }
```

(Person and category are basic classes very similar to Movie)
And these are all the imports available to the functions:

```py
from .. import db
from .dbhandler import Movie, Category, MovieCategoryScores, MoviePersonScores, Person, MovieUserScores
from .user_dbf import getUserById
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
import requests
import json
import random
from itertools import islice
from sqlalchemy import or_
```

The error above triggers when I do a simple `get_common_people(5, 10)` in a command line.

If I try to do `get_category_score(550, 0)` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1248, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 580, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/movieelo/cinelow/my_server/database/pers_movie_dbf.py", line 171, in get_category_score
    my_movie = new_query.first()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3240, in first
    ret = list(self[0:1])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3018, in __getitem__
    return list(res)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3342, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3367, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 988, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1101, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1252, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1473, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 152, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1248, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 580, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction) current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
[SQL: SELECT anon_1.anon_2 AS anon_1_anon_2, anon_1.movie_id AS anon_1_movie_id, anon_1.category_id AS anon_1_category_id, anon_1.score AS anon_1_score, anon_1.votes AS anon_1_votes, anon_1.rank AS anon_1_rank 
FROM (SELECT movie_category_scores.votes >= %(param_1)s AS anon_2, movie_category_scores.movie_id AS movie_id, movie_category_scores.category_id AS category_id, movie_category_scores.score AS score, movie_category_scores.vo
tes AS votes, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY movie_category_scores.category_id ORDER BY movie_category_scores.score DESC) AS rank 
FROM movie_category_scores 
WHERE (movie_category_scores.votes >= %(votes_1)s OR movie_category_scores.movie_id = %(movie_id_1)s) AND movie_category_scores.category_id = %(category_id_1)s ORDER BY movie_category_scores.category_id, rank) AS anon_1 
WHERE anon_1.movie_id = %(movie_id_2)s 
 LIMIT %(param_2)s]
[parameters: {'param_1': 10, 'votes_1': 10, 'movie_id_1': 550, 'category_id_1': 0, 'movie_id_2': 550, 'param_2': 1}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/2j85)
```

I found a bunch of people who had had the same problem, but none of those solutions seemed to fit what I am doing here, especially since I know this worked with SQLite but is just not working now with Postgres? It seemed to have a lot to do with *the order* of when you were ordering things vs getting their info, but I just don't get what I could possibly switch to before/after the order in my case?

Any idea of what part of the "get_common_people" function is triggering the error? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please show how the two methods are called. We need a fuller code context with all `import` lines for a [mcve]. Also, SQLite can be lenient in SQL syntax. From the raw SQL dump in error, query is indeed invalid SQL and even somewhat unclear in its intention. Are you sure that error corresponds to second function since there is no `rank` window function in raw SQL?

Comment: @Parfait I updated the post with a bunch of extra info, tell me if you would need anything else!

Comment: What is `get_person()` in loop of first `get_common_people()`?

Comment: The first traceback suggest that you are calling `get_common_categories` from `pers_movie_dbf.py` and not `get_common_people`. I think you're referring to the wrong function `get_category_score`. Have you renamed something recently?

Comment: Terribly sorry I copied the wrong function, get_common_categories is now in place instead. The get person was just a simple query to get the person object based in a persons id such as: `p = Person.query.filter_by(id=id).first()`

Comment: @Parfait I managed to solve it and posted an answer, thank you so much for your time and patience!

Answer (score 0):

All right so I managed to solve this after a lot of painstaking research. [This article](https://medium.com/@riccardoodone/the-love-hate-relationship-between-select-and-group-by-in-sql-4957b2a70229) explained super well what was happening and some ideas as how to solve it (though in regular SQL).

The problem is basically that you can't have a column that has the same values being overlapped in a group, so just like the error explains you either need to include them in the group or use a function to make them unique. So since it was my "movie_id" attribute that was messing up the common categories I simply added them together in the query so that they are now just one value and wont overlap.

In the common people function I could simply exclude all uncessecary values altogether,and the new functions look like this:

```py
def get_common_categories(movie1, movie2):
    cats = (
        db.session.query(
            MovieCategoryScores.category_id,
            func.sum(MovieCategoryScores.movie_id)
        )
        .filter(MovieCategoryScores.movie_id.in_([movie1, movie2]))
        .group_by(MovieCategoryScores.category_id)
        .having(func.count(MovieCategoryScores.category_id) > 1)
        .all()
    )
    print(cats)
    categories = []
    for cat in cats:
        categories.append(get_category(cat[0]).serialize)
    return categories


def get_common_people(movie1, movie2):
    myQuery = (
        db.session.query(MoviePersonScores.movie_id, MoviePersonScores.person_id)
        .filter(MoviePersonScores.movie_id.in_([movie1, movie2]))
        .group_by(MoviePersonScores.movie_id, MoviePersonScores.person_id)
        .subquery()
    )
    peps = (
        db.session.query(myQuery.c.person_id)
        .group_by(myQuery.c.person_id)
        .having(func.count(myQuery.c.person_id) > 1)
        .all()
    )
    people = []
    for pep in peps:
        person = get_person(pep[0])
        people.append(person.serialize)
    return people
```